# Unclear behavior in for-loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have this code in python:

```
query = "SELECT product_id FROM product_orders WHERE table_number = "+e
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
for record in records:
    query2 = "SELECT * FROM productss WHERE id = "+str(record[0])
    cursor.execute(query2)
    record2 = cursor.fetchall()
    sum=0
    for record1 in record2:
        sum = sum + record1[2]
        tree.insert("", tk.END, values=record1)

tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=sum)
```

The problem is the `sum` variable does not make summing, but stores only the last value of `record1`. Any solution for this?

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going wrong here. Firstly, there is no need to be concatenating strings for your queries (look up sql injection and parameterization) then you reset `sum` on every loop, but that tramples a builtin name

Comment: define the sum=0 at the first line and not inside the loop (and rename it to `total`)

Comment: Definitely look up SQL injection if you haven't. It's a huge security vulnerability that can be prevented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `sum = 0` inside of a for loop. Maybe if you take it out of the loop and make it a list of sums that will fix your issue. Also, as another user has said, sum is a built-in name, you can name your variable `s` instead.